# Google Data Studio Aggregation with Sum - why doesn't it sort?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

This is part of a Google Sheet I want to use as a Data Source to Data Studio:

[image]

This is what the fields in the Data Source look like:

[image]

I want to present a bar chart with the metric "Mailchimp Subscribers" and with dimension "ISO Week of the Year", grouping by the latter and aggregating the former using Sum.

To try it out, I've opened the Data Explorer and grouped according to those specifications:

[image]

From which I obtained this, which is not correctly ordered by "ISO Week of the Year":

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I didn't use google sheets or data-studio. However, I see that you are sorting according to the sum of ISO Week of the Year. I think that sum aggregation is not correct in sorting option.

Comment: @serdar you're absolutely right - the mistake was there. Switching the aggregation in the sort from SUM to AVG did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use google sheets or data-studio. However, I see that you are sorting according to the sum of ISO Week of the Year. I think that sum option in sorting may not be correct.